# Unique Id for .Net Core actions

Tags: asp.net-core

I need to have an ID for my actions to save them in DB and retrieve them for security issues.
I thought this is a unique and constant ***Id*** but it is different in every run:

```
var items = _actionDescriptorCollectionProvider
                  .ActionDescriptors.Items
                  .OfType<ControllerActionDescriptor>()
                    .Select(a => new
                    {
                        a.ControllerName,
                        a.ActionName,
                        a.Id               
                    })
```

Any idea for a unique and fixed ID for each action?

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```cs
_actionDescriptorCollectionProvider
    .ActionDescriptors.Items
    .OfType<ControllerActionDescriptor>()
    .Select(a => new
    {
        ControllerName = a.ControllerTypeInfo.FullName,
        ActionName = a.ActionName,
        ParameterTypes = a.Parameters
            .Select(p => p.ParameterType.FullName)
            .ToList()
    });
```

I think that should be unique enough.

If you are worried about the size of the ID then `ParameterTypes` could probably be trimmed down to `a.Parameters.Select(p => p.ParameterType.Name)` since I doubt you'll run into cases where that is not unique. That would for example be if you have the following two controller actions:

```
public ActionResult MyAction(string someString, MyProject.ViewModels.Banana someBanana)
{ /* ... */ }

public ActionResult MyAction(string someString, SomeOtherProject.ViewModels.Banana someBanana)
{ /* ... */ }
```

In that case `a.Parameters.Select(p => p.ParameterType.Name)` would be identical while `a.Parameters.Select(p => p.ParameterType.FullName)` would be different. So if you think that's a possible scenario, then go with `FullName`.

Comment: FullName could be repetitive when you have polyform.

Comment: @PariaShiri Not sure what polyform is. Do you mean polymorphism? If so, then how? `FullName` gives the fully qualified name of the type, no matter if it's the base type or a derived type - they won't be identical

Comment: sorry I meant polymorphism. I tried to use  a.Id  as an ID but I couldn't understand which one you suggest for ID? p.ParameterType.Name?

Comment: If the length of your ID doesn't matter that much I would go with `p.ParameterType.FullName`. Although I doubt you'll run into cases where `p.ParameterType.Name` isn't enough - `FullName` should make it completely unique, unless I'm missing some corner case that I cannot think of.

Comment: I try it and let you know the result